# Why does System.IO.Path.GetFullPath() throws exception with exact 260 characters?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Within a project we create a path to a file by using some path traveral (`\..`) to find the correct location of a file. The concrete full path to this file is always below the 260 characters mark. Now we had an exception if the traversal path is exactly 260 characters, but not if it is longer.

To show you the problem i made a little test that throws an exception i can't explain, any ideas?

```
string root = "c:\\fold";
string subfolder = "\\aFolder";
string traversal = "\\..";

// creates the string ""c:\\fold\\aFolder\\..\\aFolder\\.." ... with length 249
var pathShorterThen260 = root + Enumerable.Repeat(subfolder + traversal, 22).Aggregate((first, second) => first + second);

// Works without any problem and returns "c:\fold"
var exactPath1 = Path.GetFullPath(pathShorterThen260);

// creates the string ""c:\\fold\\aFolder\\..\\aFolder\\.." ... with length 271
var pathGreaterThen260 = root + Enumerable.Repeat(subfolder + traversal, 24).Aggregate((first, second) => first + second);

// Works without any problem and returns "c:\fold"
var exactPath2 = Path.GetFullPath(pathGreaterThen260);

// creates the string ""c:\\fold\\aFolder\\..\\aFolder\\.." ... with length 260
var pathEqualTo260 = root + Enumerable.Repeat(subfolder + traversal, 23).Aggregate((first, second) => first + second);

// Throws PathTooLongException, why?
var exactPath3 = Path.GetFullPath(pathEqualTo260);
```

Comment: After 256 you exceed MAXPATH for windows I think. Just a thought, but weird about 260 and only 260.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177665

Comment: This is .NET 4 specific behavior, it bombs on both long strings in earlier versions.  The Path.NormalizePath() method was rewritten, the algorithm is hard to reverse-engineer.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com to get the opinion of the guys that wrote the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed the bug and it is closed in [.Net 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#net-45).

For more information take a look at [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/729120/why-does-system-io-path-getfullpath-throws-exception-by-traversal-paths-with-exact-260-characters).

Answer (score 1):

You've exceeded the max path length in windows.

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH,
>   which is defined as 260 characters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Comment: But why does it then blow up with exactly 260 and works without any hassle with MORE then 260 chars?

Comment: @Oliver You can run reflector against `Path.NormalizePath()` that Has Passant mentioned in another comment. A quick search through it shows 4 places where `PathToLongException` could be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's a [`PathTooLongException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception.aspx)?  From the [`Path.GetFullPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) documentation, a `PathTooLongException` is thrown when...

> "The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length. For example, on Windows-based platforms, paths must be less than 248 characters, and file names must be less than 260 characters."

Comment: But why won't the exception be thrown when it has MORE then 260 characters and only with exactly 260 chars?